# Tensorflow - accuracy keeps at ~10%

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm really desperate for weeks, after making many changes in code...

So I developed a neural network for CIFAR-10 dataset, using the binary version data provided by https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html . But even by following network structure of https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn I am stuck at the accuracy being around 11%, oscillating.

## Weights, biases

```
def weight_variable(shape,stddev):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)
def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
```

## Convolutional Network

```
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 32,32,3])
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

  W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 3, 64],5e-2)
  b_conv1 = bias_variable([64])

  h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
  h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

  #NORM 1
  h_pool1 = tf.nn.lrn(h_pool1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,name='norm1')

  #Sec Vonc
  W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 64, 64],5e-2)
  b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
  h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
  #norm2
  h_conv2 = tf.nn.lrn(h_conv2, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,name='norm2')
  h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

  #Dense
  W_fc1 = weight_variable([8 * 8 * 64, 384],0.04)
  b_fc1 = bias_variable([384])
  h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 8*8*64])
  h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

  #Dense 2
  W_fc1a = weight_variable([384, 192],0.04)
  b_fc1a = bias_variable([192])
  h_fc1a = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc1a) + b_fc1a)

  #Dropout
  keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
  h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1a, keep_prob)

  #Readout
  W_fc2 = weight_variable([192, 10],1/192.0)
  b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
  y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
```

## Train

```
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits( logits=y_conv,labels=y_)    
cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize( cross_entropy_mean)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))      

sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: shaped_x, y_: shaped_y,keep_prob:0.5})

print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:finalttimages[0:500], y_: finalttlabels[0:500],keep_prob:1.0}))
```

> Accuracy 10% is bad, it should be at least 70%.

Can you kindly inspire me on where would the mistakes most likely hide? I'm open to discussion, comment on anything you find strange in my code. Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Does reducing the learning rate have a positive effect on the accuracy?

Comment: No, the results are still the same @ml4294

Comment: @SarajMuhammed were you able to resolve your issue? I too am facing the same situation. I have cross-verified my implementation more than a hundred times now, to no avail.

Comment: @codeahead no... Would you mind sharing your code with me at oneyandong@gmail.com ? Just for discussion.